# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate "Error Writing the Project File" C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make a C# Windows Forms Application, but whenever I try, I get this error:

"Error writing the project file."

I also get this error when I try making a Basic application or any other C# application. I tried searching the internet for a solution, but nothing worked. I tried reinstalling NuGet and MSXML6. Neither worked.

Edit

---

I am able to make c++ projects, just not C# and Basic

Comment: Is there anything in the output Window?

Comment: Make sure the directory you are trying to create the solution in is valid and not read-only and also make sure you have sufficient disk space.

Comment: @DaveShaw No, I see nothing in the output window

Comment: @icemanind The folder is read and write, and I have plenty of space.

Comment: see this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0376db8f-4761-4ae5-9af2-98c53216318a/visual-studio-setup-forum-faqs?forum=vssetup#VS_IDE_unexpected_problems

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I tried everything on that link, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of this happening - what are you doing to invoke it? Is this all projects or just this one? Can you create whole new solution & project and just accept the defaults? Then what does it do?